# Adding circles around axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, axis, axis-labels

I would like to draw a red circle around the certain labels on the y axis. I have the following data and code to make a plot:

```
data <- structure(list(group = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3"), word = c("headache", 
"computer", "window", "window", "plant", "coffee", "headache", "sky", 
"computer"), n = c(115L, 125L, 130L, 132L, 134L, 157L, 
195L, 209L, 215L), row = 1:9), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

#Define some colors to use throughout
my_colors <- c("#FFDBCE", "#8CAEAE", "#beb6d7")

wordfrequencyplot <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, n, fill =as.factor(group))) +#as factor primetype to make it discrete 
    geom_col(show.legend = F) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = "Word Count") +
    facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y","fixed_x") +
    scale_x_continuous(  # This handles replacement of row 
      breaks = data$row, # notice need to reuse data frame
      labels = data$word) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors)+
    coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()
```

I want to draw circles around the words “coffee” and “plant” in group 2, and “sky” in group 3 on the y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar to solution to the one posted by @Andrew Gillreath-Brown would be to use the `cowplot` package to draw the circles on the original plot. However, you'll need to play with the x and y values of the `circleGrob` to get the desired output.

```
library(cowplot)
library(grid)

# Draw circles as Grob
g <- circleGrob(x = c(0.38, 0.38, 0.73),
                y = c(0.51, 0.77, 0.51), 
                r = 0.05,
                gp = gpar(fill = "transparent",
                          col = "red",
                          lwd = 3))

# Use ggdraw to add the circles over the original plot
ggdraw(wordfrequencyplot) + 
  # Draw circles Grob
  draw_grob(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works well! Can I check, if I resize the plot, or knit it in HTML or word, would I need to change the x and y axis again?

Comment: I don't think you need to change the x and y in those cases, as the values correspond to a 0-1 range in both x and y axis for the plot drawn by `ggdraw`.

Comment: That is what I thought, but the circles are in different places when the plot is in the plot visualiser in rstudio, vs when I zoom and open the plot in its own window.

Comment: If you are exporting the image into a png, jpeg, etc, you might want to check the final file to make the adjustments to x and y that would output the desired positions. Sometimes there are small position differences between the visualizer of RStudio and the final exported file.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do this, but you could convert the `ggplot` object to `grob`, then use `grid.circle` from `grid` to place the circles.

```
library(grid)
library(ggplotify)
library(ggplot2)

wordfrequencyplot_grob <- as.grob(wordfrequencyplot)

plot(wordfrequencyplot_grob)
grid::grid.circle(x=0.365, y=0.784, r=0.039, default.units="npc", name=NULL,
                  gp=gpar(fill = NA, col = "red", lwd = 2), draw=TRUE, vp=NULL)
grid::grid.circle(x=0.367, y=0.511, r=0.034, default.units="npc", name=NULL,
                  gp=gpar(fill = NA, col = "red", lwd = 2), draw=TRUE, vp=NULL)
grid::grid.circle(x=0.706, y=0.511, r=0.026, default.units="npc", name=NULL,
                  gp=gpar(fill = NA, col = "red", lwd = 2), draw=TRUE, vp=NULL)
```

Output

[image]